# How to add Google Drive account if my Android device doesn't have Google Play Service

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm writing an Android app, if my Android device doesn't have Google Play Service, how can I add Google Drive account, some devices doesn't have Google Play Service in their system, I have checked google drive sdk of Android and REST API, they both depend on Google Play Service to get Google account.
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android
There is an OfficeSuite app, it uses above SDK to get Google account if current device has Google Play Service, otherwise, it will show a Google authentication page to get Google account. I have checked google drive sdk, but I haven't found the function for Android, so who know how I can do like that?

Comment: My question is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845283/google-drive-api-for-android-for-multi-account?rq=1 , nobody answers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature from Google Play Services is essential for your app there would be no way to get your App working.

You can check if the services are enabled from within your app with `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)`
which returns ***ConnectionResult.SUCCESS*** if Play Services is available.

As the Google Play Services is not a feature declared in the manifest your app should install fine on any device but may crash later on if you are using the APIs without checking if they are available.

But you can always ask the user to install the Google Play Services if they do not have on the device using this piece of code in your app.

```
public OnClickListener getGooglePlayServicesListener()
{
    return new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms"));
            startActivity(intent);

            //Finish the activity so they can't circumvent the check
            finish();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the OfficeSuite app can show a Google authentication page to get Google account., the authentication page is same as this authentication page offered by google drive sdk for IOS. Currently I don't have enough permission to upload the drawing, I have captured the Google authentication page presented in OfficeSuite app, when I have permission, I'll upload it. Anyway, the way is possible, I want to know how I can do as the OfficeSuite do, I haven't found the sdk that I can show a Google authentication page on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it out, please reference http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-oauth2-webview.html
http://ddewaele.github.io/AndroidOauth2GoogleApiJavaClient/
I have tried, it can work.

Comment: Will this solution enable me to use the Google Drive without adding the google account to Account Manager?